# C++ Переместить символ в начало строки

Tags: c++, строки

Вводим 2 строки. Например 'abcde' и 'deabc'. Есть код который перемещает символ с начала в конец строки, проверяя когда строки совпадут. Надо сделать также, но чтобы перемещало не с начала в конец, а наоборот, с конца в начало. Кто может подсказать?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1,str2;
    cin>>str1>>str2;
    int len=str1.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<" "<<str1<<endl;
        if(str1==str2){cout<<i-1<<endl;return 0;}
    str1.insert(str1.length(), str1.substr(0, 1));
    str1.erase(0, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    cout<<i<<" "<<str1<<endl;
    if(str1==str2){cout<<i-1<<endl;return 0;}
    str1.insert(str1.begin(), str1.back());
    str1.erase(len);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что надо!

Comment: рад помочь  всем,  кто хочет учиться!..